# Recursion does not seem to stop in a complicated code

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, recursion, matrix

I wrote a program to generate all possible matrices with some conditions.

It takes argument 'r' and 'n', where 'r' is the number of rows or columns in a matrix, and 'n' is the maximum number that the sum in each row or column could be

The conditions are:

1. All of the entries in each row and each column are in non-asccending order
2. The sum in each row and each column should be smaller than or equal to 'n'
3. The entries in the main diagonal are in non-ascending order( m[i][i] >= m[j][j] for all i>j)

It also has to generate all possibilities that satisfies the conditions.

So, my approach was generating 0th row and column first, and then 1st row and column, and so on, until I reach 'r'th row and column.

I did this by setting left top entry iteratively using for loops, and the calling genWat function with that left top entry, to generate all possible row entries and column entries using Boost library for combination with replacement.(http://photon.poly.edu/~hbr/boost/combination.hpp)

Then it checks the conditions, and if the generated entries fits the condition(pass the test), they are stored in the matrix(m in class Wat), and again, for the next row and column(I called it 'target'. For example, if it's dealing with the 2nd row and column, target is 2) iteratively setting left top entry and recursively calling genWat function with those left top entries.

It continues until it generate rth row and column(target == r), and if rth row and column satisfies the condition, it stores that Wat into the vector of Wat.

It was probably the most complicated program I have written ever, largely because it uses both recursion and iteration, and I found this problem really interesting, but I could not make it work, and had to ask for help.

It compiles, but when I ran the program with some small values of r and n, like 2 and 4, it keeps running forever.
For r=1, it throws out_of_bounds exception.

I think recursion is not quitting because the base case for the recursion is not defined well, but I have no idea why the program is not working.

The code is admittedly messy and long and complicated, but please help me figure out how to do this problem.

Thank you.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>
    #include<string>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<algorithm>
    #include"combination.hpp"
    using namespace std;

    class Wat {
     public:
        int r, n;
        vector<vector<int> > m;
        vector<int> sumRow;
        vector<int> sumCol;

        Wat(const int r, const int n)
         : r(r), n(n)
           m(vector<vector<int> > (r, vector<int> (r, 0))),
           sumRow(vector<int> (r, 0)),
           sumCol(vector<int> (r, 0)) { }

        ~Wat() {
            //delete m;
            //delete sumRow;
            //delete sumCol;
        }

        Wat(const Wat& source) {
            r=source.r;
            n=source.n;
            m = source.m;
            sumRow = source.sumRow;
            sumCol = source.sumCol;
        }

        Wat operator=(const Wat& rhs) {
            Wat tmp(rhs);
            std::swap(r, tmp.r);
            std::swap(n, tmp.n);
            std::swap(m, tmp.m);
            std::swap(sumRow, tmp.sumRow);
            std::swap(sumCol, tmp.sumCol);
        }

        void index_assign(int row, int col, int item) {
            (m.at(row)).assign(col, item);
            sumRow[row] += item;
            sumCol[col] += item;
        }
        void row_assign(int row, int startColIdx, vector<int> items) {
            for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {
                index_assign(row, startColIdx + i, items.at(i));
            }
        }
        void col_assign(int startRowIdx, int col, vector<int> items) {
            for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {
                index_assign(startRowIdx + i, col, items.at(i));
            }
        }
        bool checkSumForRow(int target, const vector<int>& gen_row) const {
            bool ret = true;
            int testedSum = sumRow[target];
            for (int i=0; i<gen_row.size(); ++i) {
                if(sumCol[target+1+i] + gen_row[i] > n) {
                    ret = false;
                }
                testedSum += gen_row[i];
            }
            if (testedSum > n) {
                ret = false;
            }
            return ret;
        }
        bool checkSumForCol(int target, const vector<int>& gen_col) const {
            bool ret = true;
            int testedSum = sumCol[target];
            for (int i=0; i<gen_col.size(); ++i) {
                if(sumRow[target+1+i] + gen_col[i] > n) {
                    ret = false;
                }
                testedSum += gen_col[i];
            }
            if (testedSum > n) {
                ret = false;
            }
            return ret;
        }
    };

    bool isNonAscending (const vector<int>& v);
    void genWat(const Wat& w, int target, int r, int n, vector<Wat>& vw);

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        if(argc != 3) {
            cerr << "arguments: r and n" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            vector<Wat> v;
            int r = atoi(argv[1]);
            int n = atoi(argv[2]);
            Wat waat(r, n); //starts from empty Wat, make a copy of previous Wat if needed, and add to v when complete
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                waat.index_assign(0, 0, i);
                genWat(waat, 0, r, n, v);
            }

            return 1;
        }
    }

    void genWat(const Wat& w, int target, int r, int n, vector<Wat>& vw) {
        if(target == r) {
            //compare the entries on each side beside diagonal first
            vw.push_back(w);
        }
        else if(target == r+1) {//might be the base case?? {
            return;
        }

        else {
            std::vector<int> gen_row(r-1, 0);

            do {
                if (isNonAscending(gen_row)) {
                    //need to define assignment operator, but actually to make it efficient, no need to make a copy here(just make a copy of sumRow and sumCol, and check the sum)
                    if (w.checkSumForRow(target, gen_row)) {
                        std::vector<int> gen_col(r-1, 0);
                        do {
                            if(isNonAscending(gen_col)) {
                                if(w.checkSumForCol(target, gen_col)) {
                                    Wat waaat = w;
                                    waaat.row_assign(target, target+1, gen_row);
                                    waaat.col_assign(target+1, target, gen_col);
                                    int leftTopBound = min((waaat.m)[target][target], waaat.n - max(waaat.sumRow[target+1], waaat.sumCol[target+1]));
                                    for (int i = 0; i < leftTopBound; ++i) {
                                        waaat.index_assign(target+1, target+1, i);
                                        genWat(waaat, target+1, r, n, vw);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } while (boost::next_mapping(gen_col.begin(), gen_col.end(), 0, w.m[target][target]));
                    }
                }
            } while (boost::next_mapping(gen_row.begin(), gen_row.end(), 0, w.m[target][target]));
        }
    }

    bool isNonAscending (const vector<int>& v) {
        for(int i=0; i < v.size()-1; ++i) {
            if(v.at(i) < v.at(i+1)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Does this even **compile**? `delete m;
            delete sumRow;
            delete sumCol;`?

Comment: I suggest single-stepping or emit some output at points so you can see where it is still on track and where derailed. Also when it runs "endlessly" you can break in and start stepping in debugger and look at state

Comment: and what is the 3 delete in the dtor?

Comment: You're not likely to get help on this one because it appears you're using a custom boost extension? The Combination library? As such, other people won't be able to compile this, not to mention the fact that you appear to be calling `delete` on non-pointer/array types.

Comment: You need to trim it down to just the problematic recursion.  I'm not going to sift through all the other bad code, and don't expect anyone else to.  You say it yourself, that there is no well-defined base case; and without that, recursion will not stop.  If it were recursing infinitely you should crash with a segmentation fault.  Running forever without crashing is more of an infinite loop.

Comment: I commented out the destructor when I compiled it, and I just copied and pasted to a combinations.hpp file the definition in the link I attached to use it

Comment: Of course, you realize that there are an infinite number of matrices that meet the given constraints, so, if this program is written correctly, you should expect it to still be running when the universe collapses into a singularity....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a note: There are many problems with your code. It's recommended that you post questions in such a way that they're easy for people to help with. Your code does not compile as posted and requires the use of a third-party header file. Both your destructor and constructor have errors. Regardless, in relation to the problem of the case of `r` and `n` both being equal to `1`, the following line is the problem:

`std::vector<int> gen_row(r-1, 0);`

This is called inside of the function `genWat`. With `r` equal to `1`, you are trying to make a vector of size `0`. In and of itself, this isn't necessarily a problem. But then you call `isNonAscending` and try to check the 0th index -- but the 0th index doesn't exist because the vector is of size 0!

I would focus on fixing the crash for your simplest case (`r = 1` and `n = 1`) before trying to fix your infinite loop issues.

**EDIT**: For anybody else who's interested in taking a look, the following code compiles for me on VS2010, and I believe it follows the spirit of the original code. You obviously also need to download `combination.hpp` from the link given in the question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include "combination.hpp"
using namespace std;

class Wat {
public:
  int r, n;
  vector< vector<int> > m;
  vector<int> sumRow;
  vector<int> sumCol;

  Wat(const int r, const int n)
    : r(r), n(n), m(r), sumRow(r), sumCol(r) { }

  Wat(const Wat& source) {
    r=source.r;
    n=source.n;
    m = source.m;
    sumRow = source.sumRow;
    sumCol = source.sumCol;
  }

  Wat operator=(const Wat& rhs) {
    Wat tmp(rhs);
    std::swap(r, tmp.r);
    std::swap(n, tmp.n);
    std::swap(m, tmp.m);
    std::swap(sumRow, tmp.sumRow);
    std::swap(sumCol, tmp.sumCol);
  }

  void index_assign(int row, int col, int item) {
    (m.at(row)).assign(col, item);
    sumRow[row] += item;
    sumCol[col] += item;
  }
  void row_assign(int row, int startColIdx, vector<int> items) {
    for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {
      index_assign(row, startColIdx + i, items.at(i));
    }
  }
  void col_assign(int startRowIdx, int col, vector<int> items) {
    for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {
      index_assign(startRowIdx + i, col, items.at(i));
    }
  }
  bool checkSumForRow(int target, const vector<int>& gen_row) const {
    bool ret = true;
    int testedSum = sumRow[target];
    for (int i=0; i<gen_row.size(); ++i) {
      if(sumCol[target+1+i] + gen_row[i] > n) {
        ret = false;
      }
      testedSum += gen_row[i];
    }
    if (testedSum > n) {
      ret = false;
    }
    return ret;
  }
  bool checkSumForCol(int target, const vector<int>& gen_col) const {
    bool ret = true;
    int testedSum = sumCol[target];
    for (int i=0; i<gen_col.size(); ++i) {
      if(sumRow[target+1+i] + gen_col[i] > n) {
        ret = false;
      }
      testedSum += gen_col[i];
    }
    if (testedSum > n) {
      ret = false;
    }
    return ret;
  }
};

bool isNonAscending (const vector<int>& v);
void genWat(const Wat& w, int target, int r, int n, vector<Wat>& vw);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if(argc != 3) {
    cerr << "arguments: r and n" << endl;
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    vector<Wat> v;
    int r = atoi(argv[1]);
    int n = atoi(argv[2]);
    Wat waat(r, n); //starts from empty Wat, make a copy of previous Wat if needed, and add to v when complete
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      waat.index_assign(0, 0, i);
      genWat(waat, 0, r, n, v);
    }

    return 1;
  }
}

void genWat(const Wat& w, int target, int r, int n, vector<Wat>& vw) {
  if(target == r) {
    //compare the entries on each side beside diagonal first
    vw.push_back(w);
  }
  else if(target == r+1) {//might be the base case?? {
    return;
  }

  else {
    std::vector<int> gen_row(r-1, 0);

    do {
      if (isNonAscending(gen_row)) {
        //need to define assignment operator, but actually to make it efficient, no need to make a copy here(just make a copy of sumRow and sumCol, and check the sum)
        if (w.checkSumForRow(target, gen_row)) {
          std::vector<int> gen_col(r-1, 0);
          do {
            if(isNonAscending(gen_col)) {
              if(w.checkSumForCol(target, gen_col)) {
                Wat waaat = w;
                waaat.row_assign(target, target+1, gen_row);
                waaat.col_assign(target+1, target, gen_col);
                int leftTopBound = min((waaat.m)[target][target], waaat.n - max(waaat.sumRow[target+1], waaat.sumCol[target+1]));
                for (int i = 0; i < leftTopBound; ++i) {
                  waaat.index_assign(target+1, target+1, i);
                  genWat(waaat, target+1, r, n, vw);
                }
              }
            }
          } while (boost::next_mapping(gen_col.begin(), gen_col.end(), 0, w.m[target][target]));
        }
      }
    } while (boost::next_mapping(gen_row.begin(), gen_row.end(), 0, w.m[target][target]));
  }
}

bool isNonAscending (const vector<int>& v) {
  for(int i=0; i < v.size()-1; ++i) {
    if(v.at(i) < v.at(i+1)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `combination.hpp` that you provided doesn't like when your first_value and last_value are the same.  You're telling it to generate all the combinations from 0 to 0 and it's never stopping.  I changed line 269 from:

```
     if (++(*(--last)) != last_value)
```

to

```
     if (++(*(--last)) < last_value)
```

and the code no longer runs infinitely long.

THIS IS NOT A PROPER FIX!  I have no idea if combinations are still correctly being generated by `next_mapping` and decided to leave it to you from here.

HTH